# How does one specify a file path relative to the location of the config file when Zend_Config_Ini is in use?

Tags: php, zend-framework, ini, zend-application, zend-config

I've got a common set of functionality I'd like to embed into a `Zend_Application` instance using the `configs` parameter inside of that app's `Zend_Config` instance. However, the slaved configuration file would like to be able to refer to things in a path relative to itself. For instance:

$/application/configs/application.ini:

```
[base]
config[] = APPLICATION_PATH "../CasCommon/Configs/common.ini
```

$/CasCommon/Configs/common.ini

```
[base]
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory[] = PATH_TO_THIS_IN_DIR "../Controllers"
resources.frontController.actionHelperPaths.Cas_Common_Helper = PATH_TO_THIS_IN_DIR "../ControllerHelpers"
;...
```

How might one accomplish such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP supports constants in Ini files, but unfortunately not magic constants, so you cannot use `__DIR__`, which would solve the problem. The easiest and most obvious thing would be defining the path to the application.ini file as a constant just like you did with `APPLICATION_PATH`, e.g.

```
// application.ini
foo = INI_PATH '/../somewhere/else'

// index.php
const INI_PATH = '/path/to/config/folder';
```

Then just load your `Zend_Application` regularly or instantiate a new `Zend_Config` and the constant will be evaluated like you wanted.

**Edit after comments**

I find that argument about the above being not automagic enough moot. In a standard ZF project, the `APPLICATION_PATH` is defined in the index.php file and that's also where the [default application.ini is loaded](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.application.quick-start.html). All you have to do is add the constant there. The Ini file won't exist on it's own anyway so someone will have to call an external library at some point (likely you as the developer). The above solution requires one line of setup. Any other solution requires more work.

If that is not good enough for you, you can extend `Zend_Application` to automatically add that constant before the application.ini gets loaded:

```
class My_Zend_Application extends Zend_Application
{
    protected function _loadConfig($file)
    {
        if (!defined('PATH_TO_INI')) {
            define('PATH_TO_INI', dirname(realpath($file)));
        }
        return parent::_loadConfig($file);
    }
}
```

Of course, you will still have to change index.php to use your extended `My_Zend_Application` then which is why I find this approach rather pointless given that you can also just add the constant in the index.php file.

A custom `Zend_Application` will limit you to the application.ini of course because you cannot change the constant at runtime anymore. So if you need this functionality for multiple Ini files and not just the application.ini, extend `Zend_Config_Ini` and check each value for a Relative Path marker before it is returned, e.g.

```
class My_Config_Ini extends Zend_Config_Ini
{
    protected $_relativePath;
    protected $_relativePathMarker = '%REL_PATH%';
    public function __construct($filename, $section = null, $options = false)
    {
        $this->_relativePath = dirname(realpath($filename));
        parent::__construct($filename, $section, $options);
    }
    public function get($name, $default = null)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->_data)) {
            return $this->_containsRelativePathMarker($this->_data[$name])
                ? $this->_expandRelativePath($this->_data[$name])
                : $this->_data[$name];
        }
        return $default;
    }
    protected function _containsRelativePathMarker($value)
    {
        return strpos($value, $this->_relativePathMarker) !== FALSE;
    }
    protected function _expandRelativePath($value)
    {
        return str_replace('%REL_PATH%', $this->_relativePath, $value);
    }
}
```

The above assumes you write your Ini files with something like

```
foo = %REL_PATH% '/../foo.txt'
```

If that is still not what you are looking I can only encourage you once more to put up precise requirements. There is no point in offering 500 reputation when you are not going to accept any answers here because we failed to read your mind.

Comment: Yuck. I guess it works as a workaround. Perhaps I'll build a Zend_Application_Resource that will do it... :/

Comment: Why Yuck? This is clean and simple solution. Given that you are already using `APPLICATION_PATH` why invent some additional way to achieve this over using the obvious `PATH_TO_THIS_IN_DIR` as another constant?

Comment: Because it forces me to have clients call an external library in order to use the external config. The whole point of this was to allow someone to add one line to their config and have everything work out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be (if you have the `allowModifications` option set to true) is to change the working directory, then realpath the folder. Or even prepend the path on after loading the file.

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini('config.ini', 'section', array(
    'allowModifications' => true,
));
$dir = getcwd();
chdir('..');
$config->path = realpath($config->path);
chdir($dir);
```

Comment: But how will this automatically prepend before any paths like the OP shows in the example?

Comment: @Gordon Its as automatic as manually a setting constant and putting it in the file

Comment: how so? if I set the constant it gets automatically evaluated, so a `PATH_TO_THIS_IN_DIR "../Foo` will be returned as the `/path/to/../foo`. As far as I understood your solution you are only adding a path config variable to config object.